# How to Determine in Dart when a method is Overridden?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've got a method that does the default approach when an error occurs and simply dumps the error to the user's computer screen:

```
void onError(FlutterErrorDetails details) => FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
```

Now, the user is invited to override this method, of course, but when the time comes and an error does occur, I want to know if the method was overridden or not. I can't figure out how one would do this however.

In Dart, functions are first-class objects, and so is there not a way to 'record' what the method was as the class defines it, and what it is now when the class object is instantiated? Something like:

```
  static final FlutterExceptionHandler _dumpError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);


 if (onError == _dumpError) {
     _prevOnError(details);
 } else {
      onError(details);
 }
```

Now the above doesn't work, of course. onError does not equal _dumpError. I even tried this:

```
static final FlutterExceptionHandler _dumpError = FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);

void onError(FlutterErrorDetails details) => _dumpError;
```

Now this actually works in that, when an error occurs, onError() fires and dumps the error to the console. However, it's not quite right as the comparison (==) would, again, return false. How do I make it true?: onError == _dumpError

Is there a way to do this, you think? Is there a way to compare the 'contents' of two functions??

I dunno. I'm grasping at straws at this point.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to know if the method was overridden or not. I can't figure out how one would do this however".  The point of OOP is that you shouldn't ever need to care, or even know, if that had happened.  What's your actual use case?